# Save form data in the url without page reload

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a site that has a form that I want users to be able to bookmark and that will work offline with the data they provide and also be able to create new bookmarks based on a change in form data that will be able to be created and used offline.

Imagine something like this:

```
<textarea></textarea>
<input id="save" type="button" value="save" />
<input id="go" type="button" value="go" />
```

JS:

```
$('#save').click(function() { document.location.hash = $('textarea').val() });
$('#go').click(function() { /* create DOM structure based on textarea data */ });
```

This works great but the problem is I want to also be able to serve people with js disabled.

Now if I use the hash, I lose PHP access, but if I use `document.location.search` the page will reload and it's no longer usable offline for those using js, is there anything I can do to cover everyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thou canst catch onsubmit event: if user has js enabled, do your hash stuff and cancel submission; if there's no js involved, php gets chance. Like this

```
yourForm.onsubmit = function () { /* whatever */; return false }
```

Will that do?

Comment: Yes but then the user can't give the new url with the hash change to a non js person

Comment: But can non js person ever use hash?

Comment: It works as a anchor tag, but if it doesn't find anything with the hashes name it ignores it. Js can pick up on it but PHP can't

Comment: What about putting special fields for php to feed with and print hash links then? Client script could use them too.

Comment: Apparently address bar alone can't please everyone. Let's say you give user a field where he pastes links (with hash part, the same textarea may fit). Js enabled -> offline route, js disabled -> php gets full link.